# Test for the contents of a textbox and if it matches a password then continue

Tags: c#

I'm pretty sure this has not been asked. But i'm making a password and need to make it so if the text box matches 123456 then it will do what i want. I have tried multiple things but still don't have what i need. I'm probably very stupid but its 1 am and i'm in the mood to code.

`if (text Box 1. Text = 123456){}`

Comment: Are you sure you have spaces in your variable name? That's impossible... try `textbox1.text` instead and please look at some tutorials before continuing

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I hope your text box variable name and property accessor doesn't have spaces in it, as matching a password is the least of your problems at this point.

`.Text` property is a `String` data type. So turn your numeric password into a string by surrounding it in double quotes `"123456"`. Then, instead of assigning the `.Text` property with your password you want to do a comparison: `==`

I recommend sleep also.

Comment: Hey! Thanks. one more thing im trying to make it if its not 123456 then it inputs Incorrect password. im simply using


` if(textBox1.Text == "123456"){
                this.Close();
            }else{
                label2.Text = "Incorrect Password.";
            }
        }`
all it dose is when i put 1 it puts incorrect password

Comment: @alexplue this is not a help center! Your question has been answered. I strongly recommend you make some tutorials to get at least a basic understanding of what you are trying to do